# "Freemodbus" protocol as master

Tags: stm32, modbus, stm32f4discovery, rs485

is it possible to use" Freemodbus "as master side ?
i'm going to impelement it on stm32f4xx ARM pocessor

if not ,introduce me alternative protocol that works on RS485 physical layer...

Answer (score 0):

I have looked over the website for FreeModbus and it doesn't appear that it supports master-side implementation. I'm not turning up any hits in a quick search for a Modbus master library for embedded devices. I'm sure someone has one out there, but it may not be free.

As for alternatives, that ends up being primarily opinion based and off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The FreeModbus open source code NOT contain master mode. I rewrite it and add the master. You can tyr it on stm32. https://github.com/armink/FreeModbus_Slave-Master-RTT-STM32

Answer (score -1):

You can try [this](https://github.com/armink/FreeModbus_Slave-Master-RTT-STM32) it also include Modbus Master with GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE. I am also trying it.